# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Transitional_Temperature

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am having trouble with some code I wrote. In the c.execute("""UPDATE MCE_Materials SET part python tells me that the tables'Transitional_Temperature' and 'Phase_Transition' do not exist. I have checked for possible typos, but I couldn't find any. Below I have listed the code. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import sqlite3


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x600")

if __name__ == "__main__":            
    def update():
        #Databases
        conn = sqlite3.connect('MCE_Materials.db')
            
        #Create cursor
        c = conn.cursor() #cursor executes a command
        record_id = Delete_entry.get()
        
        c.execute("""UPDATE MCE_Materials SET 
                  Name_compound = :Name_compound, 
                  Entropy = :Entropy, 
                  Magnetisation = :Magnetisation,
                  Transitional_Temperature = :Transitional_Temperature,
                  Curie_Temperature = :Curie_Temperature,
                  Hysteresis = :Hysteresis,
                  Phase_Transition = :Phase_Transition,
                  Summary = :Summary
 
                  
                  WHERE oid = :oid""",
                  {'Name_compound': Name_compound_editor.get(),
                   'Entropy': Entropy_editor.get(),
                   'Magnetisation': Magnetisation_editor.get(),
                   'Transitional_Temperature': Transitional_Temperature_editor.get(),
                   'Curie_Temperature': Curie_Temperature_editor.get(),
                   'Hysteresis': Hysteresis_editor.get(),
                   'Phase_Transition': Phase_Transition_editor.get(),
                   'Summary': Summary_editor.get(),
                   'oid': record_id
                  }) #create table and designate columns
        
        c.execute("UPDATE ")
        #Commit changes
        conn.commit() #commits the changes
            
        #close connection
        conn.close() #Close connection 
    
        editor.destroy()
        
    def Adjust():
        global editor
        editor = Tk()
        editor.geometry("400x600")
        #Databases
        conn = sqlite3.connect('MCE_Materials.db')
            
        #Create cursor
        c = conn.cursor() #cursor executes a command
        
        #record Id
        record_id = Delete_entry
        
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM MCE_Materials WHERE oid = " + record_id.get()) #Delete_Entry gets all information of 1 compound
        records = c.fetchall()    
        
        #Commit changes
        conn.commit() #commits the changes
            
        #close connection
        conn.close() #Close connection

        global Name_compound_editor
        global Entropy_editor
        global Magnetisation_editor
        global Transitional_Temperature_editor
        global Curie_Temperature_editor
        global Hysteresis_editor
        global Phase_Transition_editor
        global Summary_editor
        global Delete_entry_editor
        
        #Entry boxes
        Name_compound_editor = Entry(editor, width  = 30)
        Name_compound_editor.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        Entropy_editor = Entry(editor, width  = 30)
        Entropy_editor.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Magnetisation_editor = Entry(editor, width  = 30)
        Magnetisation_editor.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        Transitional_Temperature_editor = Entry(editor, width  = 30)
        Transitional_Temperature_editor.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        Curie_Temperature_editor = Entry(editor,  width  = 30)
        Curie_Temperature_editor.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        Hysteresis_editor = Entry(editor,  width  = 30)
        Hysteresis_editor.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
        Phase_Transition_editor = Entry(editor, width  = 30)
        Phase_Transition_editor.grid(row = 6, column = 1)    
        Summary_editor = Entry(editor, width  = 30)
        Summary_editor.grid(row = 7, column = 1)  

        
        #Labels
        Name_compound_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Name Compound")
        Name_compound_Label_editor.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Entropy_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Entropy")
        Entropy_Label_editor.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Magnetisation_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Magnetisation")
        Magnetisation_Label_editor.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Transitiontal_Temperature_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Transitional Temperature")
        Transitiontal_Temperature_Label_editor.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Curie_Temperature_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Curie Temperature")
        Curie_Temperature_Label_editor.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Hysteresis_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Hysteresis") 
        Hysteresis_Label_editor.grid(row = 5, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Phase_Transition_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Phase Transition")
        Phase_Transition_Label_editor.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)
        Summary_Label_editor = Label(editor, text = "Summary")
        Summary_Label_editor.grid(row = 7, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5)    

        
        List = [Name_compound_editor, Entropy_editor, Magnetisation_editor, Transitional_Temperature_editor,
                Curie_Temperature_editor, Hysteresis_editor, Phase_Transition_editor, Summary_editor]
        
        for record in records:
            for i in range(len(List)):
                List[i].insert(0,record[i])
                
        edit_Button = Button(editor, text = "Edit Changes", command = update)
        edit_Button.grid(row = 8, column = 0, padx = 30, pady = 5) 
        
        
#Submission change
    Change_Submission_Button = Button(root, text = "Adjust compound", command = Adjust)
    Change_Submission_Button.grid(row = 12, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10, ipadx = 100)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Edit, I forgot to add the CREATE TABLE part:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x600")
#Databases
conn = sqlite3.connect('MCE_Materials.db')
    
#Create cursor
c = conn.cursor() #cursor executes a command

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE MCE_Materials (
        Name_compound text,
        Entropy float,
        Magnetisation float,
        Transitional_Temperature float,
        Curie_Temperature float,
        Hysteresis float,
        Phase_Transtition text,
        Summary text)""") #create table and designate columns

#Commit changes
conn.commit() #commits the changes
    
#close connection
conn.close() #Close connection
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table (if you have the sqlite3 executable installed you can do `sqlite3 MCE_Materials.db` in your terminal to open the sqlite client then `.schema MCE_Materials`.

Comment: `Phase_Transtition` used in CREATE TABLE, but `Phase_Transition` used in UPDATE.